# Optimización de busqueda y respuesta json, Entity Framework

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, select2, foreach

Estoy trabajando con mvc 5 y entity framework y del lado del cliente he implementado un select2 que toma como data source una consulta ajax la duda es que si mi código es eficiente para que la búsqueda sea rápida aunque existan muchos resultados en la búsqueda, en realidad tengo duda en el foreach no se si hay una forma mas eficaz para hacer esto.

Necesito devolver los datos en el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ],
}
```

Así que cree la siguiente clase:

```
public class Select2    
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Y con este codigo busco las mesas que coincidan con la búsqueda y las convierto a el modelo de Select2.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetMesa(string q)
        {
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q))
                {
                    return Json(new { });
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Mesa> mesas = await db.Mesa.Where(x => x.NombreMesa.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower())).ToListAsync();
                    List<Select2> items = new List<Select2>();
                    foreach(var mesa in mesas)
                    {
                        Select2 item = new Select2() {
                            id = mesa.MesaID,
                            text = mesa.NombreMesa
                        };
                        items.Add(item);
                    }
                    return Json(new { items = items },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new {respuesta = "MesasController => GetMesa \n" + e.Message + e.InnerException});
            }
        }
```

¿Lo estoy haciendo de la forma mas optima?
sé que lo puedo paginar pero eso lo haré luego..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias realizar la query y obtener el objeto en la misma operacion

```
var mesas = await db.Mesa.Where(x => x.NombreMesa.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower()))
                                .Select(mesa=> new Select2() {
                                                id = mesa.MesaID,
                                                text = mesa.NombreMesa
                                            })
                                .ToListAsync();

return Json(new { items = mesas },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

entonces ya no necesitas el foreach

Comment: Exacto, es justo lo que quería lograr, muchas gracias!

Comment: ´List<Mesa>´ esta mal ya que el query devuelve ´List<Select2>´

Comment: ok edite el codigo, igual creo que la idea esta, solo era cuestion de un cambio de tipo, con el uso de "var" lo hago generico